# Register for Apple Push Notification asynchron or in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, apple-push-notifications

in my app I use push notifications and it seems to me that the request to register for push takes a while, which stops my app from immediatly displaying content and only showing a black screen until the device token comes back.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    ....

    NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    ....

    return self;
}
```

How can I do this asynchrounus or in the background.. because it confuses users if the screen stays black...

regards

UPDATE: as requested my code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.webViewCon = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [window addSubview:[webViewCon view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // register for push
    NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");    
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    return YES;
}
```

And then in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    // get token & udidi
    NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; 
    NSString *udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;

    // send request to server to save token
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://my.server.com/service/token?token=%@&udid=%@",newToken, udid];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [url release];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
}
```

and in my WebViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // create and send POST request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myUrlAddress];
    NSString *udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"udid=%@", udid];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [requestObj setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [requestObj setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [requestObj setHTTPBody: requestData];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: requestObj returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    // set delegate
    webView.delegate = self;

    // set backgroundcolor
    [webView setOpaque:NO];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:RGB(154, 148, 131)];

    // check internet and load
    NetworkStatus currentStatus = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] 
                               currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(currentStatus != NotReachable) {
        //Load the request in the UIWebView.
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"No Connection" 
                          message:@"Check your Wi-Fi connection and restart the App." 
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    // prevent scrolling up & down
    [[[webView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];

   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

hope that helps... could Reachabilit also be the problem?

Kind Regards for reading

Comment: Do you really need to send synchronous request to hit the server??

Comment: @krusty43 probably not. Should I try asynchronous NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes%3a), registerForRemoteNotificationTypes IS asynchronous:

> When you send this message, the device initiates the registration process with Apple Push Service. If it succeeds, the application delegate receives a device token in the application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method; if registration doesn’t succeed, the delegate is informed via the application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: method.

May be you do smth time consuming in callbacks of delegate?

Comment: where exactly does it state that this done asynchronous? By mentioning that the application delegate is called? Hm.. actually I do load a site in my UIWebView, but the webview already has a backgroundcolor... so this should be visible

Comment: the device _initiates_ the registration process with Apple Push Service. If you place NSLog outputs right after registerForRemoteNotificationTypes and in callbacks in application delegate, you see that first NSLog occurs earlier than outputs from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken/didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError.

Answer (score 2):

Register for notifications in AppDelegate `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` and

Try to implement these methods,

```
// one of these will be called after calling -registerForRemoteNotifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Comment: are you registering for APNS in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ?
Is `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` called before scrren goes black?? Have you tested using breakpoints?

Comment: I did register in `initWithNibName`  but now do in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is not called. I do get the device token but until that request the screen stays black

Comment: just did, do you want more from `initWithNibName` ?

Answer (score 1):

Place your code in `-(BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and it should work fine.

Comment: after my call to `initWithNibName` ?